# ¿Cómo puedo centrar el contenido de una celda en XAML?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, xaml

Estoy armando un pequeño proyecto en donde estoy mostrando algunos registros en un `DataGrid` dentro de un formulario diseñado en `XAML`, pero no logro encontrar la propiedad que me permita realizar este trabajo.

Mi código hasta el momento es el siguiente:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="grdUnidadesMedida" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,40" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="_codigoUnidadMedida" Binding="{Binding UnidadCodigo}" Header="Código Unidad de Medida" />              
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="_descripcionUniddMedida" Binding="{Binding Descripcion}" Header="Descripción Unidad de Medida"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="_estadoUnidadMedida" Binding="{Binding Estado}" Header="Estado" />
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

El proyecto esta hecho todo en C#, pero no creo que afecte esta parte del diseño de formularios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sabía si era horizontal o verticalmente pero la solución para ambos casos se daría de la siguiente manera:

```
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="_estadoUnidadMedida" Binding="{Binding Estado}" Header="Estado" />
 <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
     <Style>
       <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center">     </Setter>
       <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
     </Style>
  </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
  </DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: Hola Gbang, gracias por tu respuesta, voy a hacer las pruebas y te comento que tal me fue. Una pregunta adicional, el FrameworkElement es solo para columnas de texto?